# Combine git blame output with commit message

Tags: git, jira

Is it possible to combine `git blame` output with part of commit message (first word, JIRA ticket in my case)?

```
$ git blame file.js -L 1,5

JIRA-289 46fdf2b9 (John Smith 2015-03-24 23:47:36 +0100  1) var line1 = 1;
JIRA-111 69430b41 (John Smith 2015-03-15 23:47:36 +0100  2) aletr("smth");
JIRA-111 69430b41 (John Smith 2015-03-15 23:47:36 +0100  3) 
JIRA-289 46fdf2b9 (John Smith 2015-03-24 23:47:36 +0100  4) var line2 = line2 + 1;
JIRA-20  75fdf6bb (John Smith 2015-02-02 22:47:36 +0100  5) console.log(line2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it exactly as in your example. However, you can use `git blame --porcelain` to get a format fit for machine consumption and write a script around that.